# Как можно выписать прямые (ребра дерева обхода bfs), обратные ребра и поперечные ребра?

Tags: c++, графы

не понимаю ,как их можно выписать,но есть вариант использовать алгоритм"Время начала и конца обработки вершины",но хочу знать еще альтернативные варианты.(На фотографии теория)

Ориентированный граф задан и хранится матрицей смежности. В файле задается вершина, с которой начинается обход. Выписать прямые (ребра дерева обхода bfs), обратные ребра и поперечные ребра (не связывают предков и потомков).

Алгоритм программы:
1)bfs+добавить tine_in,time_out
2)условие для прямых ребер
3)условие для обратны ребер
4)условие для поперечных ребер

Также не понимаю все же значение слова поперечные ребра в контексте графов.

Код bfs прикреплен. https://pastebin.com/asrs22nM

Помогите,пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по тексту - не поперечные, а перекрестные

Comment: О перекрестных ребрах. Обратите внимание, что на верхнем рисунке (где неориентированный граф) у Вас изображен не просто граф, а дерево, и перекрестных ребер (так же, как прямых и обратных) в нем нет и не может. А вот в ориентированном (внизу) все они есть. Именно потому, что там уже не дерево. В неориентированном графе эти виды ребер тоже могут присутствовать (если это не дерево), но прямое и обратное ребро в неориентированном графе не будут отличаться друг от друга.